# How to trigger a bright flash like the Camera app?

Tags: iphone, ios, flash, avcapturedevice, avcapture

The way I am attempting to do a flash is this:

1) Calling

```
[device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
[device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
```

2) After 0.1 seconds I call

```
[device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
[device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
```

Problem is, the flash is way darker than the one from Camera app when it happens. I can't get that LED to shine as bright. Is there a different way to let this flash as bright as possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `setTorchModeOnWithLevel:error:`. Setting the first parameter to  1 should give you the brightest flash available.

Further documentation can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureDevice/setTorchModeOnWithLevel%3aerror%3a).